# ToList() after Select() in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is it required or not to use ToList() after Select() in this code:

```
var names = someStorage.GetItems().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Depends on whether or not you want/need an actual list or if an ienumerable suffices.

Comment: @Corak: It depends on more than that.  If you enumerate it more than once `Select` will run again. That may not be desirable.  `ToList()` forces the enumeration and gives you the results.

Comment: @EdS. - yes. An enumerable implies that you only going to enumerate it *once*. If you enumerate it more than once, then an (i)enumerable does *not* suffice.

Comment: @Corak: It's important to understand what is going on, that's the point.

Comment: @EdS. - agreed. It really does help to know the tools one uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Enumerable.ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will cause the population of data, if you do not call data wont be fetched and it will be a query.

> The ToList(IEnumerable) method forces immediate
>   query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query
>   results. You can append this method to your query in order to obtain a
>   cached copy of the query results, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

It completely depends on what your code does subsequently. The `ToList()` method causes the query that you defined by using `Select()` to run immediately against the datastore. Without it, its execution would be delayed until you access the `names` variable for the first time.

The other aspect is that, if you don't use `ToList()`, the query will be run against the datastore each time you use the `names` variable - not just once as is the case with `ToList()`. So it also heavily depends on how often you use the `names` variable (If you use it only once (e.g. in a loop), then there is no difference, otherwise `ToList()` is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your assignment variable if you assigning to list then you need to convert.

If you do not call ToList it will be a `IEnumerable<TSource>` which is the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type.

ToList converts the source sequence into a list. Some points to note:

- The signature specifies List, not just IList. Of course it
  could return a subclass of List, but there seems little point.
- It uses immediate execution - nothing is deferred here
- The parameter (source) musn't be null
- It's optimized for the case when source implements ICollection
- It always creates a new, independent list.

The last two points are worth a bit more discussion. Firstly, the optimization for ICollection isn't documented, but it makes a lot of sense:

- List stores its data in an array internally
- ICollection exposes a Count property so the List can create an
  array of exactly the right size to start with
- ICollection exposes a CopyTo method so that the List can copy
  all the elements into the newly created array in bulk

[Source to refer](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-20-tolist.aspx)

Comment: Ok, but it is more complicated than that.  If you call to list the Select will be evaluated and the result stored in a list.  If you continually enumerate the enumerable (i.e., no `ToList()`) the `Select` will run multiple times, which may or may not be what you want.  For example, call `Count()` and then do a `foreach` and you evaluate the query *twice*. Perhaps not so good for certain operations (like a DB call).

Comment: @Ed S Does it mean that if I store in cache this someStorage.GetItems().Select(x => x.Name) and do foreach for it -  Select is executed everytime?

Comment: @oblomov: Yes, it does. Every time you enumerate the IEnumerable